# IIS 7+ httpruntime not being enforced

Tags: iis, sharepoint, web-config, timeout, sharepoint-2013

So after few days of testing I've come to an end that I really don't know what is causing this issue.

I've set the httpruntime with an timeout which should be 60minutes but it didn't changed. I've also tried to change it anywhere else via IIS manager.
It always timeouts at 90 seconds.
I've also set the compilation debug to false on prod systems.
On my development system there is not such thing as this timeout from IIS.

Thanks in advance, a frustrated dev

Comment: try to set this code in your web.config file: `<system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="3600" />
</system.web>` Coul dyou please share which .net version of application pool you are using? also reffer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-3.0/e1f13641(v=vs.85)) for more detail about the httpRuntime Element.

Comment: @JalpaPanchal yes I've tried this and it has not been enforced,  I'm using 4.0 clr